# Python, splicing lists, step and only extracting first character

Tags: python, slice

I know how to do basic splicing.  But I would like to know if it is possible to splice a list, returning every 10th element and only the last 2 characters of that element.

```
['1111',' 1112',' 1113',' 1114',' 1115',' 1116',' 1117',' 1118',' 1119',' 1120',' 1121',' 1122',' 1123',' 1124',' 1125',' 1126',' 1127',' 1128',' 1129',' 1130',' 1131',' 1132',' 1133',' 1134',' 1135',' 1136',' 1137',' 1138',' 1139',' 1140',' 1141',' 1142',' 1143',' 1144',' 1145',' 1146',' 1147',' 1148',' 1149',' 1150',' 1151',' 1152',' 1153',' 1154',' 1155',' 1156',' 1157',' 1158',' 1159',' 1160',' 1161',' 1162',' 1163',' 1164',' 1165',' 1166',' 1167',' 1168',' 1169',' 1170',' 1171',' 1172',' 1173',' 1174',' 1175',' 1176',' 1177',' 1178',' 1179',' 1180',' 1181',' 1182',' 1183',' 1184',' 1185',' 1186',' 1187',' 1188',' 1189',' 1190',' 1191',' 1192',' 1193',' 1194',' 1195',' 1196',' 1197',' 1198',' 1199']
```

I can get every 10th string with no problem;

```
>>test[::10]
['1111', ' 1121', ' 1131', ' 1141', ' 1151', ' 1161', ' 1171', ' 1181', ' 1191']
```

I what to be able to get the last two characters in the above strings

So I tried this and it doesn't work.

```
test[::10][-2::]
[1181',' 1191]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use a list comprehension to apply slicing to contained elements:

```
[v[-2:] for v in test[::10]]
```

This gives:

```
>>> [v[-2:] for v in test[::10]]
['11', '21', '31', '41', '51', '61', '71', '81', '91']
```

`test[::10]` returns a list itself, and `[-2::]` just takes the last two elements from that list, and does not apply that slice to the *contained* elements of the list.

Comment: @RocketDonkey: Please, don't delete on account of a rep difference. If I did that every time someone with more rep posted I'd never have gotten the rep I have today! :-) If you feel your answer (which was only 2 seconds behind mine) has something to offer to the OP and a wider audience that my answer doesn't, do feel free to undelete!

Comment: Ha, yours is more concise anyway, and I will trust an answer from you more than myself any day :)